# Why I am getting org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, lombok

This is my model class :

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="[exclusive_data]")
public class OrderControlDataBean {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name="id")
   Long id;

   @Column(name = "Body_Code")
   String bodyCode;

    @Column(name = "Merchant_Item_No")
   String merchantItemNo;

   @Column(name = "Merchant_No")
   String no;   
}
```

This is my repository interface

```
   import java.util.List;
   import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
   import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
   import com.mypackage.mss.oas.filetransfer.app.model.OrderControlDataBean;

    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public interface OrderControlRepository extends 
     JpaRepository<OrderControlDataBean, Long> {

    public void deleteAllInBatch();

     List<OrderControlDataBean> save(List<OrderControlDataBean> 
     orderControlDataBeans);

 }
```

Below is the service tier that calls this save method:

```
 @Service
 @EnableScheduling
 public class FTPClientService {

private static final Logger logger = 
       LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTPClientService.class);

       try {
        // FTP Client connection code here//
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            OrderControlDataBean orderControlBean = extractOrderControlBean(line);

            if (!(orderControlBean.getBodyCode() == null))
                if (!(orderControlBean.getMerchantItemNo() == null))
                    if (!(orderControlBean.getNo() == null))
                        inputList.add(orderControlBean);
        }

        success = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
        repository.deleteAllInBatch();
        repository.save(inputList);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("Error while closing the FTP connection.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    logger.info("Loading OrderControl Data Completed Successfully");
}
```

I am getting arraylist populated from ftp data read its the save to database is failing.
I am getting below exception no matter what I do :

**org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!**

The database table has id [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL. This is ms sql server.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to change your method call in `Logger` from `repository.save(inputList)` to `repository.saveAll(inputList)`.

The `JpaRepository` interface will have all of those necessary methods available to you and Spring will do the heavy work behind the scenes. In fact, I believe you don't need to implement any methods in the `OrderControlRepository` and you shouldn't even need to use the `@JpaRepository` annotation. Implementing `JpaRepository` should be enough.

A great walk through of a simple one with Spring is here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/. For more details, you can go here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Thanks Dan. I believe that jpaRepository doesn't have saveAll(List) method. I want to use what is provided by the jpaRepository which I believe has  <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities); But its throwing the error as mentioned.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at the wrong version, but when I look at the javadoc (linked above), I don't see a `save(Iterable<S> entities)`, but I do see a `saveAll(Iterable<S> entities)`. If the version is different, then yes I could be off.

Comment: I am using 1.5 spring starter dependencies and Spring-Data-jpa is 1.11.11 release

Comment: Saving one entity i.e.a bean instance is working alright but it's the list that is causing the exception.

Comment: Thanks for supplying the versions; that cleared things up a bit. I'm not entirely sure then, but my hunch still lies on that fact that you are supplying your own method signature in `OrderControlRepository` for saving the list when Jpa is expecting a separate method signature since it does "magic mapping" to generate the queries. 
Maybe try removing that method signature and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks Dan, Removing the methods altogether just worked fine.